# Test angular module was lazy loading using automated builds

Tags: angular, automated-tests, loading, lazy-evaluation

I want to validate at build time programmatically that an angular module was lazy loaded. The purpose is to identify if newly added code causes a module to no longer be lazy loaded ? anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of when a lazy loaded module would be prevented from being lazy loaded when it's been specified to load via [loadChildren](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#loadChildren)? Do you mean if was prevented from loading because of route guards such as [CanLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad)?

Comment: The issue is if one of the developers references the module in another module that isn’t lazy loaded. The result is this module is no longer lazy loaded. The goal is the detect during the automated build that lazy loading was broken for a specific module through the introduction of code being checked in